# How to pick some value from Struct and put into new List in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have list of struct something like this..

```
[ %Phonebook{name: "Family", id: 3},  %Phonebook{name: "Friend", id: 2},
  %Phonebook{name: "Relatives", id: 1} ]
```

And I want to be something like this..

```
["Family": "3", "Friend": "2", "Relatives": "1"]
```

How can I do this using Elixir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to have a [`Keyword`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Keyword.html#content) with string keys in Elixir in the first place.

Without loss of generality, we might assume you have maps, not structures. So, here you go, with a [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension:

```rb
list = [
  %{name: "Family", id: 3},
  %{name: "Friend", id: 2},
  %{name: "Relatives", id: 1}
]

for %{name: name, id: id} <- list, do: {name, id}
```

Please note, that what you get back is exactly what you asked for.

```rb
#⇒ [{"Family", 3}, {"Friend", 2}, {"Relatives", 1}]
```

If these were atoms, you’d get a Keyword in a form you expect:

```rb
for %{name: name, id: id} <- list, do: {String.to_atom(name), id}
#⇒ [Family: 3, Friend: 2, Relatives: 1]
```

Whether you want a `map` back, use `into` argument in the above call:

```rb
for %{name: name, id: id} <- list, do: {name, id}, into: %{}
#⇒ %{"Family" => 3, "Friend" => 2, "Relatives" => 1}
```

---

*Sidenote:*

```rb
[{:Family, 3}, {:Friend, 2}, {:Relatives, 1}] ==
  [Family: 3, Friend: 2, Relatives: 1]
#⇒ true
```

---

Also, the same functionality might be achieved with [`Enum`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html) methods, like [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#map/2):

```rb
Enum.map(list, fn item -> {item.name, item.id} end)
```

or in it’s short form:

```rb
Enum.map(list, & {&1.name, &1.id})
```